# Грамотная передача исключений

Tags: c++, исключения

Знаю, что в JAVA передача исключения реализуется через объекты класса.

В С++ же можно передавать не только объекты класса, что, как мне кажется, не всегда грамотно с точки зрения программирования.

Можете, пожалуйста, привести какой-нибудь более или менее реальный, грамотный пример передачи исключения в С++?

Comment: @usk-dima, уверены, что Вам [действительно хочется использовать exceptions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38449/C-Exceptions-Pros-and-Cons)?

Comment: @avp по-моему, причины не использовать исключения из приведенной вами статьи если не надуманы, то как минимум вряд ли способны перевесить пользу от их использования.

Comment: @DreamChild, на самом деле [реальная проблема лежит глубже](https://toster.ru/q/27307), а может [и еще глубже](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/OO_programming/).

Но, как это не покажется странным, на практике такое положение дел всех устраивает...

Comment: @avp, @DreamChild: Мне кажется, проблема как исключений, так и объектно-ориентированного подхода (мне эти вещи кажутся несвязанными) заключается в следующем: люди считают их чем-то большим, чем они есть на самом деле. ООП не отменяет необходимость думать и правильно выстраивать абстракции. Классы есть не самоцель, а лишь помощник добиться инкапсуляции (которой в принципе можно добиться и другими методами). Если программист не осознаёт необходимость инкапсуляции, ему рано пользоваться классами (или другим инструментом). Бездумное пользование мощными средствами вполне может сделать код хуже.

Comment: ...Исключения не есть метод, который ликвидирует необходимость думать об ошибках, а код, позволяющий переносить ошибку по стеку с его автораскруткой. Они точно так же не отменяют необходимость думать, придерживаться определённых принципов в программировании (тот же самый принцип «вычисление, потом коммит», например) и понимать, что именно происходит в коде.

Одним словом, разруха как обычно в головах.